# ImageDataGenerator.flow() gives IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, keras

I was following the tutorial given here: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

On executing the first half i.e. the data preprocessing code :

```
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
save_to_dir='preview', save_prefix='cat', save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i > 20:
        break
```

I get the error :

```
`fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'preview/cat_0_7886.jpeg`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does a "preview" directory exists?

Comment: I tried executing with and without the directory. I get the same error.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Mac OS Sierra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`save_to_dir` must have the full path and you have to create all directories in that path before hand

Example:
`save_to_dir=r'C:\ML\augImage\train'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path like `/tmp/preview` after making sure that path exists

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I fixed using

```
folder = "training_blond_sep" (no slash or backslash)
(...)
for batch in datagen.flow_from_directory(folder, classes=['cat1','cat2'], target_size=(180,180), batch_size=100,  shuffle = False, seed=7, save_to_dir=folder+'/aug', save_prefix="changed"):
```

but I had to create this folder manually.

Hope this helps.